# Why does GeoJSON map looks stretched in Highmaps for WSG84?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, maps, geojson, highmaps

I am trying to migrate a map (used Polymaps so far) to Highmaps. If I use the world map provided from the Highmaps collection (which is `EPSG: 102014`, unusual coordinates), everything looks fine. If I use a GeoJSON file that comes in the WSG84 (`EPSG: 4326`) format, then all the shapes look horizontally stretched.

The solution that I used for some maps was to simply grab a GeoJSON file in the format that Highmaps likes, but for this particular case it's not possible.

**[Expected result](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/ee72c7f0598da9e12ee9&map=3/68.88/1.23)**

**[What I actually get](http://jsfiddle.net/6w4gra6v/)**

What I tried so far is converting the original GeoJSON from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 102014, but it still looked bad. Is there any way I can make that original GeoJSON look good on Highmaps?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue, and would be interested in knowing how you solved it

Comment: Hi, I haven't found any way to fix this. What I did was using a map that Highcharts provide in their map library.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the EPGS4326 (WGS84) so I reprojected my geojson to EPGS3857 (web mercator) and in highmaps looks right.

In their [web](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon) they have an example that use the proj4js library to reproject on the fly, but I not been able to make it work to transform from 4326 to 3857, so I reproject the original geojson.

The transform is supposed to work including this on the geojson:

```
"hc-transform": {
    "default": {
        "crs": "Your map projection in proj4 string format, as supported by pro4js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that using the maps from the Highmaps library is a better way to go than trying to fiddle with my old ones.